# Azure Blob CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin Ignored by the browser

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

I've setup a new blob storage account on my Azure account and configured it to allow CORS using the following configurations:

```
serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
            serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Delete,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 1800 // 30 minutes
            });
```

And yet I still get the following error from my js code:

```
Origin <MY-SITE-URL> not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
```

Looking on the response headers of the image, I see:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So why doesn't it work?

Comment: What kind of operation are you trying to perform? Can you share your JavaScript code as well?

Comment: Where can I set the CORS property in azure blob dashboard? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the withCredentials property on the xmlhttprequest to true? If yes the browser will reject wildcard Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Check out the following links for more helpful information:

- [Azure storage CORS returns origin wildcard and fails in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475143/azure-storage-cors-returns-origin-wildcard-and-fails-in-browser)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx